# Dynamically create a matrix of radiobutton from two textbox inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to create a matrix of radio buttons based on two arrays one having label and count for rows and another one having label and count for column.

These arrays are obtained from two textboxes, where users enters texts separated by semicolon:

```
<input type="text" name="criteria" id="criteria" class="Textbox autobox default" value="row1;row2;row3;row4" autocomplete="off">
<input type="text" name="levels" id="levels" class="Textbox autobox default" value="level1;level2;level3;level4;level5" autocomplete="off">
```

Then I tried to create radio buttons dynamically for a row using:

```
var array1 = $('#criteria').val().split(";");
var array2 = $('#levels').val().split(";");

for (j = 0; j < array2.length; j++) {
for (i = 0; i < array1.length; i++) {
   var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" name="rbtnCount" />');
   radioBtn.appendTo('#matrix');


}
$('#matrix').append("<br/>"); 
}
```

I manage to produce rows of radio buttons but I could not get for each new row as new group and with labels.

I expected a matrix of radio buttons like in the following figure: [image: matrix]

Users should be able to select one in each row therefore each row is in different groupings so that selection in one row does not affect other.

Comment: Is "array" supposed to be "array1"?

Comment: in your fiddle you still didn't change an array to array1 (on line 3) and an array to array2 (on line 10)

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create a runnable example here on Stack Overflow so people don't have to toggle to jsfiddle.net...

Comment: Check this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/euLpf2wh/

Comment: Yes, that solved first part of the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/w3rjchzL/5/ now i need to create matrix of radio button. Thanks @phishfordead

Comment: @Shiva, you must group radiobuttons by setting them with the same name attribute.  Your result html should have unique names per row.

Comment: @Shiva Check out this fiddle, this should get you going :) http://jsfiddle.net/uxbkc86f/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different row wise groupings can be made by setting same name for every radio element in that row. In the following snippet, names of radio buttons are set from the criteria array elements.

The id for every radio button should be unique, hence a combination of row and column iterators can be made to set up their ids (e.g. '00','01','02', etc.).

It is advised not to make too many DOM update calls by using element.append() inside loops. Instead, you can form your entire HTML string and append it at the very end of your script.

```js
$('#criteria').change(function() {
  updateMatrix();
});

$('#levels').change(function() {
  updateMatrix();
});

updateMatrix();

function updateMatrix() {
  var innerHTML = "";
  var criterias = $('#criteria').val().split(";");
  var levels = $('#levels').val().split(";");
  $.each(criterias, function(i) {
    if (i === 0) {
      innerHTML += "<tr><th></th>";
      $.each(levels, function(j) {
        innerHTML += `<th> ${levels[j]} </th>`;
      });
      innerHTML += "</tr>";
    }
    innerHTML += "<tr>";
    $.each(levels, function(j) {
      if (j === 0) innerHTML += `<td> ${criterias[i]} </td>`;
      innerHTML += `<td><input type="radio" name="${criterias[i]}" id="${i}${j}"></td>`;
    });
    innerHTML += "</tr>";
  });
  $('#matrix').html(innerHTML);
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.text-label {
  display: block;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}

.textbox {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 300px;
}

table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

table input {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

th,
td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

th {
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="text-label">Criteria</span>
  <input class="textbox" type="text" name="criteria" id="criteria" value="row1;row2;row3;row4" autocomplete="off">
</div>
<div>
  <span class="text-label">Levels</span>
  <input class="textbox" type="text" name="levels" id="levels" value="level1;level2;level3;level4;level5" autocomplete="off">
</div>

<table id="matrix">
</table>
```

Comment: Its just fabulous. Thanks. Using table produces nice matrix. Just one more doubt....how would I update the variables criteria and levels upon the textbox is changed and the table is dynamically updated? Thanks again.

Comment: You can embed everything in a function that can be called to re-render your matrix, and use jQuery change() Method to detect value changes on your textbox and call the re-render function. Check the updated snippet for your reference.

Comment: Thanks it does exactly.